# set max-height for my modal window based on the current screen window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, razor

I have the following script which will show a modal window for my partial view:-

```
$(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {        
            $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');

                bindForm(this);
            });
            return false;
        });


    });
```

and I set the following css:-

```
#myModalContent {
   max-height: 400px;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

but let say on a small size window the max-height of 400px will not be consistent if the actual screen size is less than this such as in a mobile screen.
so my question is how I can set the max-height for the modal window to be 80% of the current screen size ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `$("#myModalContent).css("max-height", screen.height * .80);`

That might work

Comment: how I can apply this in my case,, before the .load ?

Comment: I tried this $('#myModalContent').css("max-height", screen.height * .80).load(this.href, function () { and it worked by minimizing the modal size to be 80% but I did not get any scroll bar,, so I defined the following as a css rule #myModalContent {
  
   overflow-y: auto;
}. but I am not sure if I can apply overflow:auto inside the script alos ?

Comment: Ok so instead of .css("max-height", screen.height * .80) do 

.css({
    "max-height": screen.height * .8,
    "overflow-y": "auto"
})...

Answer (score 0):

Just use % insted of px in the stylesheet

Comment: I tried this #myModalContent {
   max-height: 70%;
   overflow-y: auto;
} but this will not show any scroll bar ,

Answer (score 0):

For pure css solution.

```
#modalname .modal-body {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

here 100vh-> 100% of height. 200px is the approx combine space(height) used by modal header and footer.

css solution is better than js as on window size change, it will directly adjust the height of the modal.